# Primefaces SelectOneMenu with same item values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu with twice the same value. When i choose item "One" and then try to change to item "Two", nothing happens. I unterstand that the values are the same, but i would like the correct Label to be displayed.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selectedValue}">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="One" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Two" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Three" itemValue="3" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

But if i select "Three", it works corectly. The Label changes.

i Use Wildfly 8.2 and the PF v5.1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is impossible and a very, very uncommon usecase

Html  is designed to have unique values in a select...  Think of it, If you preselected '1' from e.g. a database, which label should be shown? 'One'? or 'Two'? Non-unique labels works for the server, but that is confusing for the client. So having both 'unique' is not weird

Comment: The use case is with dynamic select items created by the customer. He configures credit cards types and their corresponding accounts. He has many credit cards types (Visa, mastercard, ...) and all payments are booked in the same account.

Comment: XY problem…  the ui is not responsible for this, the business logic is. Create a map on the server side that maps individual unique values from a select to a common account id

Comment: you can even use an arraylist with the index of the selectitem as a key

Comment: I'm wondering why the GUI reacts like that but i accept your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Ummm... because html  is designed to have unique values in a select...  Think of it, If you preselected '1' from e.g. a database, which label should be shown? 'One'? or 'Two'? Non-unique labels works for the server, but that is confusing for the client. So having both 'unique' is not weird